# Не работает вывод ошибки об отсутствии аргумента

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    @commands.command(name = 'clear')
    async def delete_messsages(self, ctx, amount):
        if not amount:
            await ctx.send('Ты не указала кол-во сообщений!')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = int(amount))
            await ctx.send(f'{amount} сообщений было удалено!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаём значение по умолчанию для аргумента amount, и потом проверяем равняется ли он None

```
@commands.command(name = 'clear')
    async def delete_messsages(self, ctx, amount=None):
        if amount is None:
            await ctx.send('Ты не указала кол-во сообщений!')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = int(amount))
            await ctx.send(f'{amount} сообщений было удалено!')
```

или

```
@commands.command(name = 'clear')
async def delete_messsages(self, ctx, *amount):
    if not amount:
        await ctx.send('Ты не указала кол-во сообщений!')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = int(amount[0]))
        await ctx.send(f'{amount[0]} сообщений было удалено!')
```